Extracting rotational-free translational information out of transformation matrix?
I use SIFT feature detector and need the angle AND the center translation of two rigid2D transformed images.
Therefor I want to extract the information directly out of the transformation matrix.
Attached is a minimum working example. The idea is to to build a rotation matrix with the angle I get from the image registration and then extract backwards via matrix multiplication the translation matrix. I think it should work but some small thing is missing. Goal of the minimum working example is to calculate the initial set parameters (tx,ty,angle) out of the image registration.
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv, cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

img=cv2.imread(r"\lena_std.tif",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

tx=0 #parameters to play which should be totally compensated by the code
ty=0
angle=60

rows,cols= img.shape

rot_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cols/2,rows/2),angle,1)
rot_mat=np.vstack([rot_mat, np.array([0,0,1])])
trans_mat = np.array([
    [1, 0, tx],
    [0, 1, ty],
    [0, 0, 1]
], dtype=np.float32)
M=trans_mat @ rot_mat

reference_image = img
test_image = cv2.warpAffine(img,M[:2,:3],(cols,rows))

def similarity_sift_flann_affine2D (reference_image, test_image):

    img1=test_image.astype(np.uint8)
    img2=reference_image.astype(np.uint8)

    # Initiate SIFT detector
    sift = cv.SIFT_create()
    # find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
    kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
    kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2,None)
    FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 1
    index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
    search_params = dict(checks = 50)
    flann = cv.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
    matches = flann.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)
    # store all the good matches as per Lowe's ratio test.
    good = []
    for m,n in matches:
        if m.distance < 0.7*n.distance:     #Lowes ratio test
            good.append(m)
        
    MIN_MATCH_COUNT=10
        
    if len(good)>=MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
        src_pts = np.float32([ kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
        dst_pts = np.float32([ kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
        M, mask = cv2.estimateAffinePartial2D(src_pts, dst_pts)
        #M,mask = cv.estimateAffine2D(src_pts, dst_pts)
    
    else:
        print( "Not enough matches are found - {}/{}".format(len(good), MIN_MATCH_COUNT) )
        matchesMask = None
        
    return M

M1=similarity_sift_flann_affine2D (reference_image, test_image)

sizeImg1=img.shape
u, _, vh = np.linalg.svd(M[0:2, 0:2])   
R = u @ vh
angle2 = math.atan2(R[1,0], R[0,0])
angle2 =np.rad2deg(angle2)

cor_rot_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cols/2,rows/2),-angle2,1)
cor_rot_mat=np.vstack([cor_rot_mat, np.array([0,0,1])])

M1=np.vstack([M1, np.array([0,0,1])])
#cor_trans_mat= np.linalg.inv(cor_rot_mat) @ M1
cor_trans_mat= M1 @ np.linalg.inv(cor_rot_mat)

print("angle diff", str(np.abs(angle2)-np.abs(angle)))
print("tx diff", str(np.abs(tx)-np.abs(cor_trans_mat[0][2])))
print("ty diff", str(np.abs(ty)-np.abs(cor_trans_mat[1][2])))

Can someone help? Many thanks!

What do you mean by "with not angle-independent translations".  Define how you need your translation. The coefficients of cv2.estimateAffinePartial2D() should give you the angle and translations.  See the matrix showing at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#gad767faff73e9cbd8b9d92b955b50062d

Hi @fmw42, thanks. I added some information in the question. I want the translation in that way, that it is independent of the rotation, so that I can first correct the angle of the offset image and then translate the offset image.

Can't you use the rotation part of the matrix to rotate the center point and then subtract from the original center? Is that what you want?

Hi @fmw42, yes, thats exactly what I want and what I tried. But depending on which point (center, corner, ...) I rotate the image about there is always a point (center of rotation) which doesnt get affected by the rotation and on that point I should be able to applly the translation information of the matrix directly. But since the translation parameters change with the angle, that doesnt seem to work. What is it that I dont get?
To my understanding the transformation matrix maps every point of image2 to image 1.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I tried to make the question more clear.

I found the solution, the theory behind my code was correct. The error was the sign of angle2 and I commented out the wrong inverse matrix multiplication.
This code works:
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv, cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

img=cv2.imread(r"\lena_std.tif",cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

tx=36 #parameters to play which should be totally compensated by the code
ty=120
angle=30

rows,cols= img.shape

rot_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cols/2,rows/2),angle,1)
rot_mat=np.vstack([rot_mat, np.array([0,0,1])])
trans_mat = np.array([
    [1, 0, tx],
    [0, 1, ty],
    [0, 0, 1]
], dtype=np.float32)
M=trans_mat @ rot_mat

reference_image = img
test_image = cv2.warpAffine(img,M[:2,:3],(cols,rows))

def similarity_sift_flann_affine2D (reference_image, test_image):

    img1=test_image.astype(np.uint8)
    img2=reference_image.astype(np.uint8)

# Initiate SIFT detector
    sift = cv.SIFT_create()
# find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
    kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
    kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2,None)
    FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 1
    index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
    search_params = dict(checks = 50)
    flann = cv.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)
    matches = flann.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)
# store all the good matches as per Lowe's ratio test.
    good = []
    for m,n in matches:
        if m.distance < 0.7*n.distance:     #Lowes ratio test
        good.append(m)
    
    MIN_MATCH_COUNT=10
    
    if len(good)>=MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
        src_pts = np.float32([ kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
        dst_pts = np.float32([ kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
        M, mask = cv2.estimateAffinePartial2D(src_pts, dst_pts)
        #M,mask = cv.estimateAffine2D(src_pts, dst_pts)

    else:
        print( "Not enough matches are found - {}/{}".format(len(good), MIN_MATCH_COUNT) )
        matchesMask = None
    
    return M

M1=similarity_sift_flann_affine2D (reference_image, test_image)

sizeImg1=img.shape
u, _, vh = np.linalg.svd(M[0:2, 0:2])   
R = u @ vh
angle2 = math.atan2(R[1,0], R[0,0])
angle2 =np.rad2deg(angle2)

cor_rot_mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cols/2,rows/2),angle2,1)
cor_rot_mat=np.vstack([cor_rot_mat, np.array([0,0,1])])

M1=np.vstack([M1, np.array([0,0,1])])
cor_trans_mat= np.linalg.inv(cor_rot_mat) @ M1

print("angle diff", str(np.abs(angle2)-np.abs(angle)))
print("tx diff", str(np.abs(tx)-np.abs(cor_trans_mat[0][2])))
print("ty diff", str(np.abs(ty)-np.abs(cor_trans_mat[1][2])))

